# Workaround for a breaking change in ConnectedMoleculeComponents from 12.1.1 to 12.2.0

Tags: bugs, chemistry

The following code used to work in `Mathematica Version 12.1.1`:

```
ClearAll[mol];
mol = Molecule["NC(Cc1ccc(O)c(I)c1)C(=O)O", IncludeHydrogens -> True];

{mol, {"DeleteAtom", 2}} //
Apply[MoleculeModify] //
ConnectedMoleculeComponents
```

The atom with index 2 is highlighted below:

[image]

In `Mathematica Version 12.2.0`, the code works up to the call to `Apply[MoleculeModify]`. But on invoking `ConnectedMoleculeComponents` I get the following errors:

> During evaluation of In[415]:= KeyMap::invak: The argument >LibraryFunctionError[LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR,6][atomPropertyAssociation] is not a >valid Association.
>
> During evaluation of In[415]:= KeySort::invrl: The argument
> KeyMap[FromDigits][LibraryFunctionError[LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR,6][atomPropertyAssociation]]
> is not a valid Association or a list of rules.
>
> During evaluation of In[415]:= KeyValueMap::invak: The argument
> KeySort[KeyMap[FromDigits][LibraryFunctionError[LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR,6][atomPropertyAssociation]]]
> is not a valid Association.
>
> During evaluation of In[415]:= Molecule::nintrp: Unable to interpret
> LibraryFunctionError[LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR,6][Atom[Missing[KeyAbsent,getAtomsList]]]
> as a name or chemical identifier.
>
> Out[417]= MoleculeModify[Molecule[{   "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
> "O", "C", "I", "C", "C", "O", "O",     "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H",
> "H", "H", "H"}, { Bond[{2, 3}, "Single"],  Bond[{3, 4}, "Aromatic"],
> Bond[{4, 5}, "Aromatic"],  Bond[{5, 6}, "Aromatic"],  Bond[{6, 7},
> "Single"],  Bond[{6, 8}, "Aromatic"],  Bond[{8, 9}, "Single"],
> Bond[{8, 10}, "Aromatic"],  Bond[{11, 12}, "Double"],  Bond[{11, 13},
> "Single"],  Bond[{10, 3}, "Aromatic"],  Bond[{1, 14}, "Single"],
> Bond[{1, 15}, "Single"],  Bond[{2, 16}, "Single"],  Bond[{2, 17},
> "Single"],  Bond[{4, 18}, "Single"],  Bond[{5, 19}, "Single"],
> Bond[{7, 20}, "Single"],  Bond[{10, 21}, "Single"],  Bond[{13, 22},
> "Single"]}, {}], {"ExtractParts", {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
> 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}, {11, 12, 13, 22}, {1, 14,
> 15}}}, ValenceErrorHandling -> False]

[The last time I complained about breaking changes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216583/is-there-a-place-where-wolfram-research-announces-breaking-changes-for-new-relea) in the latest version, which was then `Mathematica Version 12.1.0`, I was admonished to first [check the notice on incompatible changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html). This time, I did check the link. But there is nothing at that link on `ConnectedMoleculeComponents`.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a workaround for this problem?
2. Is there any hope of influencing Wolfram Research to publish a more thorough list of breaking changes, preferably weeks before the new version is out?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-report-bugs

Comment: An error spew like this is not an intentionally introduced change, it's a bug that I will try to fix.  I'll post a workaround here later if no one else does it first.  On your previous question you were not *admonished* to check that link, your question specifically asked where that information is posted.

Comment: @Jason B. thank you for adding the `bugs` tag. And I want to clarify that I meant "admonished" more as a recommendation than a reprimand. I was happy to learn of that list. It's just that I have a rather large code base that uses all of your chemistry packages extensively. But you've been very helpful in the past, so I don't doubt this will get fixed.

Comment: you should take note of the change "AtomQ of Molecule objects now returns True." for 12.2.  This means that you cannot use `Part` or `First` or similar functions on a `Molecule`, in the same way you cannot use those functions on a `Graph`.  This was a good change going forward, but I am worried about its potential to break code.

Comment: I already did! I had a line like `mol // {Apply[Sequence], myMolFunc} // Through`, which I had to replace with `mol // {{AtomList, BondList} /* Through /* Splice, myMolFunc} // Through`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until the bug is fixed, this should work as a replacement for [`ConnectedMoleculeComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedMoleculeComponents.html):

```
fixStereo[indices_, replacement_][stereo_] := If[
    SameQ[Complement[Select[Flatten @ Values @ stereo, IntegerQ], indices],
        {}
    ],
    replacement @ stereo, Nothing
];
moleculePart[mol_, indices_] := Module[
    {
        atomlist = AtomList[mol, indices],
        bondlist = BondList[mol, indices],
        options = Options @ mol,
        fixIndices = ReplaceAll[Thread[indices -> Range[Length[indices]]]]
    },
    options = Replace[
        options,
        {
            RuleDelayed[
                HoldPattern[Rule[opt:AtomCoordinates | AtomDiagramCoordinates, x_]],
                opt -> Part[x, indices]
            ],
            HoldPattern[Rule[StereochemistryElements, x_List]] :> (StereochemistryElements -> Map[fixStereo[indices, fixIndices], x])
        },
        {1}
    ];
    Molecule[atomlist, fixIndices @ bondlist, options]
];
connectedMoleculeComponents[mol_] := Map[
    moleculePart[mol, #]&,
    ConnectedComponents @ MoleculeGraph @ mol
]
```

For the example it works just fine,

```
mol = Molecule["NC(Cc1ccc(O)c(I)c1)C(=O)O", IncludeHydrogens -> True] // 
    MoleculeModify[{"DeleteAtom", 2}] // connectedMoleculeComponents
```

[image]

Comment: Confirmed that this works for me. Thanks again, @Jason B.